# Dplyr filtering based on two variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, spread

I want to use `dplyr` to determine which observations in a dataframe meet the following condition:

- Within each `Group`, the combined total of `Var2` for observations where `Var1 == good` is greater than the combined total of observations where`Var1 == bad`

Here's the toy dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(seed = 10)

df <- data.frame("Id" = 1:12,
                 "Group" = paste(sapply(toupper(letters[1:3]), rep, times = 4,simplify = T)),
                 "Var1" = sample(rep(c("good","bad"),times = 1000),size = 12),
                 "Var2" = sample(rep(1:10, times = 1000),size = 12))

print(df)

   Id Group Var1 Var2
1   1     A good    6
2   2     A  bad    9
3   3     A good   10
4   4     A good    7
5   5     B  bad    9
6   6     B  bad    1
7   7     B  bad    6
8   8     B good    6
9   9     C good    1
10 10     C  bad    8
11 11     C good    4
12 12     C  bad    2
```

So far I've determined that I should be using some combination of `group_by()`,`summarise()`, and `filter()` but I can't seem to wrap my head around a good way to do it. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
keepers <- df %>% 
        group_by(Group, Var1) %>%
        summarise(Total = sum(Var2)) %>% 
        print()

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: Group [?]

  Group  Var1 Total
  (chr) (chr) (int)
1     A   bad     9
2     A  good    23
3     B   bad    16
4     B  good     6
5     C   bad    10
6     C  good     5
```

What next steps should I take? Ultimately the analysis should return "A", because it's the only `Group` where `Total` is greater for the `good` observations than for the `bad` observations.

Comment: Note: first time posting to SO! Please help me out if I've formatted this question in incorrectly or awkwardly. Constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: Very neat question for a first ask, +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `spread` than `filter`:

```
> library(tidyr)
> df %>% group_by(Group, Var1) %>%
+    summarise(Total = sum(Var2)) %>%
+    spread(Var1,Total) %>%
+    filter(good>bad)
Source: local data frame [1 x 3]

  Group bad good
1     A   9   23
```

Comment: This works! I made a mistake in my answer, but before I could fix it, @fishtank already provided a correct answer.

Comment: This solution is exactly what I was looking for! @fishtank thanks for introducing me to the `spread` function!

Answer (score 2):

A similar option with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Group', 'Var1', get the `sum` of 'Var2', reshape from 'long' to 'wide' and filter the rows where the 'good' is greater than 'bad'.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df)[, sum(Var2) , by = .(Group, Var1)], 
               Group~Var1, value.var='V1')[good>bad]
#   Group bad good
#1:     A   9   23
```